# Make a field required if another field is checked in Django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model like this:

```
class News(models.Model):
    is_activity = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    activity_name = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True, null=True)
```

What I am trying to achieve is, if `is_activity` is checked in I want `activity_name` to be required. Thus, I am trying to override the `__init__` method:

```
class NewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = News

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.fields['is_activity'] is True:
            self.fields['activity_name'].required = True


class NewsAdmin(FrontendEditableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = NewsForm
```

Even if I check in the `is_activity` the `activity_name` is non-required. What's wrong?

Comment: self.fields is a dictionary mapping the fields instance on your form not the values you passed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `ModelForm.clean()` method gives you access to the cleaned data – this is where you can include the field-specific conditional logic:

```
from django.core.validators import EMPTY_VALUES

class NewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = News

    def clean(self):
        is_activity = self.cleaned_data.get('is_activity', False)
        if is_activity:
            # validate the activity name
            activity_name = self.cleaned_data.get('activity_name', None)
            if activity_name in EMPTY_VALUES:
                self._errors['activity_name'] = self.error_class([
                    'Activity message required here'])
        return self.cleaned_data

class NewsAdmin(FrontendEditableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = NewsForm
```

Comment: If anyone else's also trying to adapt this for django-cms plugins: in your `cms_plugins-py` add `from django.forms import ModelForm` and `from cms.admin.placeholderadmin import FrontendEditableAdminMixin` to your `cms_plugins.py`. And yes, your admin definition will look like this: `class MyPlugin(FrontendEditableAdminMixin, CMSPluginBase):`